# Where is temporary DB when i test hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing

I do JUnit tests for hibernate with property

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:mylogin.sqlite</property>
```

When testing changes are not in my real database, but i can't find temporary one. `find / -iname 'mylogin.sqlite'` didn't find anything. Where it is located?

Comment: mylogin.sqlite, according to the documentation, is a relative file path. So it's located in the directory from which the application is being started. You can specify an absolute file path, still according to the documentation.

Comment: Dear JB Nizet, it sounds logic, but the fact is when i do changes in JUnit tests i see it applied, but i can't see it in DB tables. In another words i add record (`session.saveOrUpdate()`), then check it and see that record exists (`criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult())`), but table is empty in DB-navigator. That's why i get stuck. How such  thing can happens?

Comment: Dear JB Nizet, accept my apologies. Something magic and irrational happened and changes now are applied and i see them. i just recreated db manually and voila!!! 0_o

Anyway many thanks for your answer...